# lein-bin clojure plugin making executable jar/zip malloc error bug?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

On Mac OS X 10.9.5 when I run 'lein bin' the binary is generated, but gives the following error when run:

```
paul$ target/event-hub-cli 
-bash(64435,0x7fff7e177310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fdd7d10f190: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

But when I run the uberjar it works.

```
paul$ java -jar target/event-hub-cli-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar 
Hello, World!
```

My project.clj is the following

```
(defproject event-hub-cli "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "An event hub client"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [edu.byu.eventhub/eventhub-client "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :main event-hub-cli.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}}
  :plugins [[lein-bin "0.3.4"]]
  :bin {:name "event-hub-cli"
        :bin-path "~/bin"}
)
```

Is this a bug or am I simply using the plugin incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Try using version 0.3.5 of `lein-bin`, it should fix your issue:

```
:plugins [[lein-bin "0.3.5"]]
```

I tried to build your project on my Mac OS X 10.10.5 (and Java8). `lein bin` failed with plugin version 0.3.4, but worked with version 0.3.5.